# Template specialization and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11

Suppose I have a template class with a lot of functions and I want to specialize them to change only a few of them and keep the other ones exactly as specified in the base template class.

How can I do that?

Below is what I want to achieve, but the solution isn't good, because it does not allow me to refer to the specialization for `int` as `Base<int>` – I need to use `IntSpec` for that.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Base
{
  void print1() {cout << "Base::print1" << endl;};
  void print2() {cout << "Base::print2" << endl;};
};

struct IntSpec : public Base<int>
{
  void print2() {cout << "Base<int>::print2()" << endl;};
};

int main()
{
  Base<double> d;
  // Base<int> i;  <-- I want this kind of instantiation
  IntSpec i;

  d.print1();
  d.print2();
  i.print1();
  i.print2();
}
```

The output is:

```
Base::print1
Base::print2
Base::print1
Base<int>::print2()
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Nicol's solution works fine, but this is an alternative:

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
  void print1() {cout << "Base::print1" << endl;};
  void print2() {cout << "Base::print2" << endl;};
};

template<>
void Base<int>::print2() {cout << "Base<int>::print2()" << endl;};
```

That way you can specialize only specific member functions and still use those that you haven't specialized(in this case, `print1`) without any problem. So now you'd use it just like you wanted:

```
Base<int> i;
i.print1();
i.print2(); // calls your specialization
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/495h0f).

Comment: Are you sure that's standard C++, or a compiler extension?

Comment: @NicolBolas I for myself always thought that is perfectly valid (and wondered why it wasn't the top answer right away), but that doesn't need to mean anything (though, I think to remember having once explicitly searched for this in *Vandevoorde-Josuttis*, and found it).

Comment: @NicolBolas I believe §14.7.3/14 allows doing this. Am I wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work when your template class has several parameters and you want to specialize a method for one of them.

Answer (score 29):

You just have to use two template classes:

```
template<typename T>
struct CommonBase
{
  void print1() {cout << "Base::print1" << endl;};
  void print2() {cout << "Base::print2" << endl;};
};

template<typename T>
struct Base : public CommonBase<T>
{
};

template<>
struct Base<int> : public CommonBase<int>
{
  void print2() {cout << "Base::print2" << endl;};
};
```

You always use `Base`, rather than `CommonBase`.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to add a level of indirection in the function you want to redefine, i.e.

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    template<typename T2>
    void bar_impl()
    {
        //generic function
    }

    void bar()
    {
        bar_impl<T>();
    }
};
```

Then you can specialize each function individually for each type or specialize the whole type as wanted.