# Template specialization of pure virtual method

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class, template-specialization, overriding

Expected this code to compile and work

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

template<>
void Base<int>::method() { std::cout << "overrided" << std::endl; }

Base<int> base;
```

But it gives the `'Base<int>': cannot instantiate abstract class` error. Thought partial specialization would make `Base<int>` non-abstract and allow to instantiate it.

Is there a working solution as short as this one and that keeps the `Base` class abstract? Otherwise I can make the `Base` class non-abstract or use Nicol Bolas's solution from here: [Template specialization and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056579/template-specialization-and-inheritance)

Comment: Even for regular abstract class you can have a definition for the pure virtual function. But that doesn't make it any less abstract. You still wont be able to create an instance of it.

Comment: @Arunmu An answer better phrased as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @AlanStokes I agree with you, but I don't think I have answered the OP with that comment.

Comment: @OP Between, you are not trying (utimately) partial specialization , but _full_ specialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it won't work for a non-template class, why should it work for a template class?

```
#include<iostream>

class Base
{
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

void Base::method() { std::cout << "overrided" << std::endl; }

Base base;
```

errors:

```
10 : error: cannot declare variable 'base' to be of abstract type 'Base'
Base base;
^
3 : note: because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Base':
class Base
^
8 : note: virtual void Base::method()
void Base::method() { std::cout << "overrided" << std::endl; }
^
Compilation failed
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just assumed that definition of pure virtual functions make abstract classes non-abstract.

Answer (score 2):

What about specialization of whole class (instead of just one member function):

```
template<class T>
struct TempClass
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

template <>
struct TempClass<int>
{        
    virtual void f()
    {
       //...
    }
};
```

Note that `TempClass<int>`  is no longer *abstract class*, but other `Base` classes are still abstract classes, (`TempClass<float>`, `TempClass<double>`, `TempClass<SomeClassType>`, `...`).

and

it won't contain fields that generic class `TempClass` contains. You will have to copy-paste them from generic Base *or*, which is more clever solution,

you'll create base class with fields that both specialization have and then make those template classes inherit from that base class:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
   // some members that all Base classes have
};


template <typename T>
struct TempClass: Base<T>
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};


template <>
struct TempClass<int>: Base<int>
{
    virtual void f()
    {
       //...
    }
};
```

This way ugly copy-paste wasn't needed.

Comment: You say TempClass<int> won't contain fields of the generic class TempClass. Why?

Comment: @Aleksey Because each *class template specialization* is considered as distinct (new) class template.

Comment: thanks for the help, I thought template specialization worked like inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to provide an implementation of a pure virtual function in a class. That does not make the class instantiable.

```
class Base
{
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

void Base::method() { /* Do something */ }

// This is still a problem since Base
// is still an abstract class, i.e. it is not still not
// instantiable.
Base base;
```